# Using sed command in Ansible playbook

Tags: shell, sed, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to  return the version from my `pom.xml` using the command below, but it doesn't work.

```
- name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    shell: "echo cat \/\/*[local-name()='project']\/*[local-name()='version'] | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '\/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'"
    register: ArtifactId
- debug: var=ArtifactId.stdout_lines
```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a basic shell problem, rather than an Ansible problem.  That command line generates an error even without ansible:

```
$ echo cat \/\/*[local-name()='project']\/*[local-name()='version'] | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '\/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The argument to the `cat` command is insufficiently quoted, and you appear to be escaping the forward-slash (`/`) which is unnecessary and may in fact cause problems.  Try this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: >
        echo cat '//*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]' |
        xmllint --shell pom.xml |
        sed '\/^\/ >/d' |
        sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
      register: artifactId

    - debug:
        var: artifactId.stdout_lines
```

Using the `>` folded scalar operator lets you avoid a level of quoting, and that makes the command easier to manage.  It also allows you to format it to be more readable.

Given the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</project>
```

The above playbook results in:

```
TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "artifactId.stdout_lines": [
        "4.0.0"
    ]
}
```

While this works, you might want to consider using some sort of XPath module for ansible instead.  [This one](https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml) appears to have recent activity, although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: i have test it in debian but it prints diffrent result with 2 lines:

`ok: [localhost] => {
    "artifactId.stdout_lines": [
        " -------",
        "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    ]
}`

Comment: It sounds like right now you may simply need to fix your XPath expression. 
 If you would like to update your question with a reproducible example (a runnable playbook *and* a corresponding `pom.xml` that results in the described behavior) I would be happy to take a closer look.